# Retrieving JSON data via HTTP POST using Spring Android Framework

Tags: android, spring-3, resttemplate, rest-client

I am using spring android framework for retrieving json data via Http POST. But while consuming the service, at server side the parameter are received null.

Following is the android code :

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
String username = params[0];

String password = params[1];

String url = connectServices.connectLoginServiceURL();// returns url

loginServiceParam = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
loginServiceParam.add("username", username);
loginServiceParam.add("password", password); //username and password are null at server end.

HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application", "json")));
requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(loginServiceParam, requestHeaders);

// Create a new RestTemplate instance
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

// Add the Gson message converters
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

// Make the HTTP POST request, marshaling the response from JSON

ResponseEntity<LoginBean> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, LoginBean.class);

LoginBean loginBeanResponse = responseEntity.getBody();

status = loginBeanResponse.getStatus();

return status;
}
```

LoginBean class is following :

```
public class LoginBean {

    private String status;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

The json response is :

```
{"status":"true"}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I myself resolved this query. 
Following code needs to be put

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(true);
```

True is required for POST request. 
By default it is false and that is for GET request.
This is not mentioned even on [Spring Android Reference link](http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e435)

Comment: Arpit, this is incorrect. The `true` parameter has nothing to do with POST or GET requests. Passing `true` to a new RestTemplate instance indicates to add a set of default message converters. See the Reference doc here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e161 Also the API doc: http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#RestTemplate(boolean)

Comment: Roy, thanks for the information. I was able to process POST only if    `true` is passed to the RestTemplate. Without that I was encountered following exception  : `org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap]`